# how to set height and width for cells in backrid

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

i have integrated [backgrid.js](http://www.backgridjs.com/) in my current assignment everything is working fine but i would like to know that how to set height and width for a cell in the `backgrid` table?

Is it possible to change the width and height of the backgrid table also how to use on mouse over events on the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery and CSS for changing cell height and cell width.  You should also be able to use the css classes for cells to detect hovers as well.

Take a look at http://backgridjs.com/misc/styling.html.  It explains all the classNames used for the different cell types.

Sorry I can't offer you any examples.  I'd need a better explanation of your problem for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use CSS. You are using Backgrid so you have table with class 'backgrid'. Override existing Backgrid CSS. For example:

```
 table.backgrid td {
   //do something 
 }
```

Same as above, you can override height and width of backgrid table.